# Transform a parent/child table to a fixed column dimentional table

Tags: sql-server, pivot, olap, recursive-query

I've a relational table (id, parentId, name)

which I'd like to convert to a flattened dimentional table

(id, Level1, Level2, Level3, Level4)

I'm ok fixing the depth at 4 deep.

I've made progress with a recursive CTE and pivot, but the result set isn't right

I get

```
Id  Name   Level1 Level2
0   Root   NULL   NULL
1   NULL   L1     NULL
```

but I need

```
Id  Name   Level1 Level2
0   Root   NULL   NULL
1   Root   L1     NULL
```

here's what I have to date

```
with rcte as
(
      select h.id
      ,h.parent_id
      ,h.name
      ,1 as HierarchyLevel 
  FROM RelTable h
  where id = 1
  union all
  select h2.id
       , h2.parent_id 
      , h2.name
      , r.HierarchyLevel + 1 AS HierarchyLevel 
  FROM RelTable h2
  inner join rcte r on h2.parent_id = r.id
 )
select id, parent_id, [1] as L1,[2] as L2,[3] as L3, [4] as L4
from (
select id,parent_id,name,HierarchyLevel from rcte
) as src
pivot  ( max(name)  for HierarchyLevel   in ([1],[2],[3],[4]) ) as pvt
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: might help if you showed us what data you're starting with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overcomplicating the solution? If it's fixed at four deep then it can be done with some simple joins...

```
SELECT
    L1.id as ID
    L1.Name as Level1
    L2.Name as Level2
    L3.Name as Level3
    L4.Name as Level4
FROM
    RelTable as L1

        INNER JOIN
    RelTable as L2
        ON L1.id = L2.ParentID

        INNER JOIN
    RelTable as L3
        ON L2.id = L3.ParentID

        INNER JOIN
    RelTable as L4
        ON L3.id = L4.ParentID
```

As an exercise in using CTEs its useless, but it does what you need.